# I can't push my code to the remote devOps repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, authentication, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I have a project on azure devOps which consists of two Repos .. I cloned the first Repo via Visual Studio 2019, and I'm working on the second Repo via VS Code. The Problem is that I can't push my code to both Repos.
On visual studio, I got this error:

> Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details

and on VS Code, I got that error:

> Failed to authenticate to git remote:"*Repo_url*"

I hope that someone can help me find some solution…

Comment: Did you "See the Output window for more details"? What did that say? What URL did you use to clone from Azure DevOps?

Comment: "Done building project "WebApi.csproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 3 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="
That was written in the output window. There wasn't any info about the problem itself.
The Url : "https://FatmaMedhat97@dev.azure.com/FatmaMedhat97/Gp/_git/Graduation%20Project%20Frontend"

Comment: You're looking at the wrong output in the output window. change to "Show output from: **Source Control - Git**"

Comment: Does that URL have protocol prefix? Did you use SSH or HTTPS? I'm thinking you used SSH when you should use HTTPS. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Authentication failed for 'https://dev.azure.com/FatmaMedhat97/Gp/_git/Graduation%20Project%20Backend/'
Pushing to https://dev.azure.com/FatmaMedhat97/Gp/_git/Graduation%20Project%20Backend

Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
Pushing main
git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
This is writen in the output window .. i'm using https and yeah i'm on window

Comment: So are you on Mac OS X? Are on Windows?

Comment: I'm on Windows and I eventually solved the problem on visual studio, but I still can't push from vs code

Comment: @ZyadTarek do you mean can you push to both repos with Visual Studio? And neither with VS Code? If that's not what you meant, note it's easy to switch repos in both VS and VS Code, if you want to test this.

Answer (score 0):

You could download git Batch tool and then cd into your current repo directory and then run：

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

**Then**, try to push your code code again.

**Besides**, the error always is caused by the current user permission of the repos. So please enter **Project Settings** under Azure Devops--> **Repos**-->**Repositories** --> enter into your specific repo --> **Security** and then check the every option into **Allow** for your current user account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the **windows credential**. Follow the steps below to solve the problem:

1. In the window 10 search bar, type **Credential Manager‌**.
2. In the credential manager window, click on **Windows Credentials**.
3. Among the items displayed, click on the IP address of your remote
   DevOps repository and click on **Remove** from the Edit and Remove options.
4. Then, be sure to close VS Code‌.
5. **Run as administrator** your Internet Explorer.
6. Enter the IP address of your remote DevOps repository in the
   Internet Explorer.
7. In the opening prompt, enter your username and password of the
   remote DevOps repository (if there is) and then click the save
   credential check.
   Now open VS Code‌ again and push and synch your code.